# AssemblyResolve always get raised, asking for MyAssembly.resources

Tags: .net, wpf, resources, assemblies, assembly-resolution

I have a WPF application, and I subscribe to the event [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwdd50tz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (this event get raised whenever the runtime does not find an assembly), and I notice it gets call several times trying to resolve MyAssembly.resources, where MyAssembly is the current executing assembly. It also asked the same thing for a library assembly I referenced from MyAssembly (it asked for Library.resources).

Is this normal? How do I fix it? My application does have a problem. It cannot load some xaml user control located in the library. Is this related?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your AssemblyInfo.cs and your resolver will not get asked for resources any-more.

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]
```

Though this is a work-around should be carefully considered multi-language applications.

More Info:

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526836/wpf-appdomain-assemblyresolve-being-called-when-it-shouldnt
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kimhamil/archive/2008/11/11/what-does-the-neutralresourceslanguageattribute-do.aspx
- http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/c-wpf-appdomain-assemblyresolve-being-called-when-it-shouldn-t-669567.html

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this same problem with an `AssemblyResolve` event handler.  Oddly, we only saw the issue on Windows XP machines. Our application is localized to many languages, so we were hesitant to use the `NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute`. Our application was compiled for .NET v3.5, but was still being affected by the `AssemblyResolve` change [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) for .NET v4.0:

> **Important** Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the ResolveEventHandler event is raised for all assemblies, including
>   resource assemblies. In earlier versions, the event was not raised for
>   resource assemblies. If the operating system is localized, the handler
>   might be called multiple times: once for each culture in the fallback
>   chain.

The way we resolved this was to check `e.Name` and see if it was looking for *.Resources.dll. If that file was not found in the AppDomain or known folder, we would remove ".Resources" and look for *.dll. If that file exists, we load and return that assembly. This resolved the problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fuslogvw.exe in order to see where .Net is trying to look for your dependencies.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx for more info.